# python sympy polygon.angles() return wrong values

Tags: python, geometry, sympy, polygon, angle

I have some geometric forms represented by polygons and I m trying to get all angles in each polygone

I am trying to get all angles of a polygon with this code :

```
polyline=((0,0),(8,8),(15,8),(15,0),(23,0),(23,20),(0,20))
point2D_poly=[]
for p in polyline :
    point2D_poly.append(Point2D(p))
points=tuple(point2D_poly)
poly = Polygon(*points)
for i in range(len(polyline)):
    angle = poly.angles[point2D_poly[i]].evalf()*180/math.pi
```

It returns 45 degree for the angle (0,0) (correct) but returns 315 instead of 45 when I change the order of points in the polygone like this :
polyline=((8,8),(15,8),(15,0),(23,0),(23,20),(0,20),(0,0))

Answer (score 0):

seems like it is actually finding the outer angle at the 0,0. it might be found sequence of the inner angle is greater than the outer. so it doesn't know what is out or what is inner. so my guess is it might be taking the external angles of the polygon.

Comment: the idea behind this function is to get the inner angle. have u an idea how to do this ?

Comment: This can be reported as a bug. The docstring indicates that the angles dictionary should contain the internal angles.

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24885) for issue

Answer (score 0):

The routine tries to keep track of whether vertices are being traversed in a cw or ccw direction. I think it should base this on the number of left or right hand turns, not on a single left or right hand turn. The following will ignore direction:

```py
def angles(self):
    args = self.vertices
    ret = {}
    direction = [self._isright(args[i-2],args[i-1],args[i]) for i in range(len(args))]
    t = direction.count(True)
    f = len(direction) - t
    assert t != f
    cw = t > f
    for i in range(len(args)):
        a, b, c = args[i - 2], args[i - 1], args[i]
        ang = Ray(b, a).angle_between(Ray(b, c))
        if cw ^ direction[i]:
            ret[b] = 2*S.Pi - ang
        else:
            ret[b] = ang
    return ret
```

So

```py
>>> tot = lambda x: sum(angles(x).values())
>>> v = (0,0),(8,8),(15,8),(15,0),(23,0),(23,20),(0,20)
>>> tot(Polygon(*v)) == tot(Polygon(*reversed(v))) == 5*pi
True
```

Comment: it seems that the code miss the definition of  _isright() function

Comment: it's not a function, it is a method of the Polygon object